# Windows WSL error when creating Next.js app

Tags: windows, ubuntu, next.js, wsl-2

I installed WSL 2 on Windows to create some apps. When I tried to create a next.js app with **'npx create-next-app@latest'** in **'/home/lucastso/dev'**, my terminal showed me this message:

√ What is your project named? ... meetsphere
√ Would you like to use TypeScript? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use ESLint? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use `src/` directory? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to customize the default import alias? ... No / Yes

Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
[Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Windows\meetsphere'] {
errno: -4048,
code: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'mkdir',
path: 'C:\Windows\meetsphere'
}

[image: Message]

I don't know how to solve this. Can anyone help me?

Tried to change all security problems

Answer (score 0):

It might be that WSL is using Nodejs that was installed in Windows, which leads to the problem, that it can't use the paths from WSL and produces this error:

```bash
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

Then it tries to generate the new project inside of `C:\\Windows\\<project>`, which is not working because of access rights.

### Check Nodejs location in WSL

- Open a terminal for your Linux, like "Ubuntu"
- Execute this command: `which node`

If this doesn't output anything, then it's very likely that you are using the Nodejs from Windows.

### Install Nodejs in WSL

- Open a terminal for your Linux, like "Ubuntu"
- Execute `sudo apt install nodejs` to install Nodejs

(Or use a node version manager like [fnm](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm) to be able to switch to any version you want)

- Check the location of Nodejs in the WSL terminal: `which node`
- This will show you the location of Nodejs inside of WSL